# select a node from json string

Tags: php, json

I am trying to use the google translation API as shown on this page...

https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/using_rest

When I replace my API key, it works correctly and display the translated text as shown below.

GET https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=INSERT-YOUR-KEY&target=de&q=Hello%20world

```
{
    "data": {
        "translations": [
            {
                "translatedText": "Hallo Welt",
                "detectedSourceLanguage": "en"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I will like to return only the text i.e. "Hallo Welt" using PHP.

I used json_decode function, but it returns everything.

Comment: What's your PHP Code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$url = "https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=INSERT-YOUR-KEY&target=de&q=Hello%20world";
$data = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($data);

echo $json->data->translations[0]->translatedText;
```

Comment: This does not return anything. But print_r($json->data->translations); returns Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [translatedText] => Hallo [detectedSourceLanguage] => en ) )

Comment: Edited the answer, translations is an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
$object = json_decode($yourJSONString);
echo $object->data->translations->translatedText;
```

Once you have used [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), you just use the resulting object however you use any other PHP object.